# SwiftUI: SIGABRT involving unrelated components (WatchConnectivity, AppStorage, Foreach, ...)

Tags: swift, swiftui, sigabrt, watchconnectivity, swiftui-foreach

My app crashes at startup since I have added WatchConnectivity.
I have simplified the app until anything I remove also removes the bug.

Now this minimal app is in a weird state where whenever I remove completely unrelated things the bug disappears.
E.g. the bug disappears if I replace the `@AppStorage` property with `@State`, or if I choose a different variation of the `.fullScreenCover()` modifier, or if I remove the `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)` modifier on the rows in the `ForEach` view, or if I replace the `ForEach` view with the content of the `ForEach` view.

I imagine the issue is some kind of race condition.
If I found out why this happens I could make sure there is no way the bug randomly appears again.

To reproduce simply create a new iOS app in XCode and replace all the code inside `ContentView` with this:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import WatchConnectivity

struct ContentView: View {

    @StateObject var connectivity = Connectivity()
    @AppStorage("setupKey") var hasBeenSetupBefore: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        let sheetBinding = Binding<ActiveSheet?>(
            get: {
                if !hasBeenSetupBefore {
                    return ActiveSheet.setup
                } else {
                    return nil
                }
            },
            set: { _ in }
        )
        Text("Hello World")
            .fullScreenCover(
                item: sheetBinding,
                content: { _ in
                    WelcomeScreen()
                }
            )
    }

    enum ActiveSheet: Identifiable {
        case setup, settings

        var id: Int {
            hashValue
        }
    }
}

struct WelcomeScreen: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(features) { feature in
                    Text("hello")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    let features = [
        Feature()
    ]
}

struct Feature: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
}

class Connectivity: NSObject, ObservableObject, WCSessionDelegate {

    @Published var activationState = WCSessionActivationState.notActivated

    override init() {
        super.init()

        if WCSession.isSupported() {
            let session = WCSession.default
            session.delegate = self
            session.activate()
        }
    }

    func session(
        _ session: WCSession,
        activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState,
        error: Error?
    ) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.activationState = activationState
        }
    }

    func sessionDidBecomeInactive(_ session: WCSession) {}

    func sessionDidDeactivate(_ session: WCSession) {}

    func updateComplication(with data: [String: Any]) {}

    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String: Any] = [:]) {}
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce on Xcode Version 13.0 beta 5 on simulator or a real device

Comment: I'm using Xcode 12.5.1 and iOS 14.5 on simulator. The same error also happened on a real device although the above code doesn't seem to crash on my physical iPhone XR with iOS 14.7.1.